# How to avoid duplicate values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have almost 10 token machines where customers are getting token numbers from table `Token`. I am using a stored procedure for accessing this table and updating it

```
Id    Name       TokenFrom   TokenTo   LastUsedToken
----------------------------------------------------
1     Token         551        999         562
```

I have notices that during rush hours a lot of customers are getting duplicate numbers. Maybe this problem is showing up because 10 customers are getting tokens at the same time/hour/second.

Here is `issuedToken` table

```
Id  PosId   Barcode        Date                      Status  Number isTaken 
1   2       6282019214317  2016-10-20 09:41:45.020    1      366        1
2   2       6282019215918  2016-10-20 09:42:15.020    1         367     1
3   2       6282019225016  2016-10-20 09:42:45.020    1         368     1
4   3       6282019230812  2016-10-20 09:42:55.020    1         369     1
```

Even sometimes same number is coming on two cashier machines also. I am getting and updating Next Token Number on POS using this `Update` statement

```
UPDATE POS 
SET tNo = (SELECT TOP 1 NUMBER 
           FROM Tickets 
           WHERE STATUS = 1 
             AND isTaken = 1 
             AND PosId = (SELECT CGROUP 
                          FROM POS 
                          WHERE NAME='ABC')) 
WHERE NAME = 'ABC'
```

I have 3-3 POS in one group that's why selecting `cGroup` and in table it's `PosId`.

I have asked question related to this question before in this question, where someone help me to write a stored procedure for accessing Token Number easily.

But still I am having duplication issue. Can anyone tell me what the best way to avoid duplication ?

[What is Best Approach for Auto Increament](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39830614/what-is-best-approach-for-auto-increament/39830777#39830777)

Comment: @RyanVincent, customers are entering 10 digits National ID in token system and getting token numbers

Comment: Is a token just an incrementing number? (please explain). Use a `sequence` or an `identity` (insert a record then use `scope_identity`). Any other convoluted MAX or manual locking method will just give you problems.

Comment: @RyanVincent, by the way i am generating a 13 digit unique barcode as well when issuing ticket

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes it's incrementing number only. nothing else

Comment: I suggest you use an identity or sequence but first I must convince that it's a bad idea to have a special range of ticket number for special purposes. Why do ladies need to be 1-50? what happens if you get more than 50 ladies in a day. Anyway did you link to your other question because that is the way you implemented it? That'll definitely give you duplicate tokens

Comment: @RyanVincent, see my edited post now

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, i am sure at the same time there not more than 40 Womens whose ticket status is open...

Comment: That might be the case but why impose magic numbers when you don't have to? Anyway if you use a sequence you can implement these magic numbers if you like.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, i have just categorized sections nothing else

Comment: Based on your question here, the solution is to create a token table with an identity column, insert into it and use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the number back out. That guarantees that multiple requests for a token will get you unique numbers. But you have a load of extra stuff here back in your original question, and in this question you have barcodes. You need to explain this further.

Comment: The way this is always done is you create a table with an identity column and create a calcaulated column with a barcode based on the value of the identity value. That satisfies the requirement of a unique number and a barcode. You need to establish whether all this other stuff (special ranges for departments etc.) is really a business requirement or not. I suspect not.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i have 13 digits unique barcode for each and every Token that is generating from this system.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, `issuedToken` is a table that is storing Token Issued. It have an Auto Increment identity column name `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works in SQL 2008 but does not take into account groupings,  does not reset, and has a different formula for barcode

This is the token issued table. Inserting a record in here 'reserves' the token number:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[issuedToken2](
    [Token] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Barcode]  AS (((6820000000.)+[Token])*(100)+[PosID]),
    [GenerationDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PosID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[issuedToken2] 
    ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_issuedToken_GenerationDate]  
    DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [GenerationDate]
GO
```

This is a stored procedure that you can use to get a token number. You can have 100 systems calling this simultaneously and they'll all get a different number:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[pGetToken]
@PosID INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

insert into issuedToken2 (PosID) 
VALUES(@PosID)

RETURN scope_identity()
END
GO
```

This is how you use it all: call the stored proc with a posid (in this example 7) to reserve the token number, then use it to get the barcode:

```
DECLARE @Token INT

EXEC @Token = pGetToken 7

SELECT @Token, [Barcode]
FROM issuedToken2
WHERE Token=@Token
```

Basically this works by using an `identity` - an incrementing number. I know your existing system doesn't work like this but you haven't explained why it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes you have SQL Server 2012 (please clarify)

Not a complete answer but I can expand if you wish.

First create a sequence (just run this once):

```
create sequence CustomerCare 
    as integer
    start with 51
    increment by 1
    minvalue 51
    maxvalue 350
    cycle;
```

now get the next sequence from it (run this as often as you like):

```
select next value for CustomerCare
```

This method can't hand out the same number to two different requests so you won't get duplicates. It will automatically wrap around when it gets to 350. You can create and use sequences for your other groupings. Much simpler than the other solution and 100% reliable.

Again I need to advise against creating magic number ranges for specific groups.

Comment: I have Sql Server 2008 R2

Comment: So even 20 Token Machines are requesting number at the same time it will not be duplicate ??

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008 R2 Express Edition. When i am trying to run this query. here is error.

Unknown object type 'sequence' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.

Comment: sequences only work on SQL Server 2012. I'll update your post and think of another solution

Comment: Yeah, tell me something that can work on SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I can tell you something that works (using identity and `scope_identity`) but there won't be any special number ranges for groups, and your barcode will need to be generated off the identity. You haven't given any explanation about how your barcode is generated

Comment: Here is logic for barcode generation. 628 + `select substring(replace(replace(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),120),' ',''),'-',''),':',''),7,11) as DATETIME` + 01. Where 01 is hostId

Comment: Did you know that will also have collisions? at 55 past the hour, host id 2 will have a barcode ending in 57. At 56 past the hour, host id 1 will also have the same barcode ending in 57.

Comment: Then give me some new logic to generate 12 digits unique code in sql... i am using EAN13 so last 1 digit will be auto generated

Comment: Oh I thought you were adding 1 second for host 1, 2 seconds for host 2 etc. but it looks like maybe you're concatenating it.... in which case sorry yes it will be unique - I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've added another answer below - try it out. I'm going to sleep now - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by changing my Stored Procedure that is accessing Next Number. Now logic is to lock `Token` table and getting next number. Now i am getting only unique numbers.

Thanks everyone for your kind responses.